# ProFTPD - how to show target symlink file size and date in directory listing

Tags: linux, proftpd

I have a FTP directory with a lot of symbolic links inside (ln -s). 
Currently directory listing in FTP client shows size and file date of symbolic link  instead of target file. Thus listing shows file size 0 and date of file is always a date of symbolic link creation...

Please let me know if there is an option to display FTP directory listing with target files attributes.

Answer (score 1):

For FTP there is a server option

```
ShowSymlinks on
```

which might help You with that. It's provided by mod_ls.
I think it will not work with SFTP.